# sending negative bytes with tcp

Tags: java, tcp

I am sending a byte by a TCP connection, when I send a single negative number (like `-30` in this example) I get three bytes:

Client Side:

```
PrintWriter out = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream())));
out.write((byte)-30);
out.flush();
out.close();
```

Server Side:

```
is = new DataInputStream(clientSocket.getInputStream());
is.readFully(bbb);
for (int i=0;i<bbb.length;i++)
    System.out.println(i+":"+bbb[i]);
```

what i get is:

```
0:-17
1:-65
2:-94
```

but I sent just `-30`

Comment: what happens if you use basic outputstreams and inputstreams?

Comment: `PrintWriter` suggests it does some "formatting" of the value being passed. Have you looked at the documentation?

Comment: Thanks every body, yes i used basic output stream and it works now, Thank you SO MUCH!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using a writer, and you're calling [`Writer.write(int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/Writer.html#write-int-):

> Writes a single character. The character to be written is contained in the 16 low-order bits of the given integer value; the 16 high-order bits are ignored.

So you've got an conversion to `int`, then the bottom 16 bits of that `int` are taken. So you're actually writing Unicode character 65506 ([U+FFE2](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ffe2/index.htm)), in your platform default encoding (which appears to be UTF-8). That's not what you *want* to write, but that's what you *are* writing.

If you only want to write *binary* data, you shouldn't be using a `Writer` at all. Just use `OutputStream` - wrap it in `DataOutputStream` if you want, but *don't* use a `Writer`. The `Writer` classes are for text.

Comment: Thanks, i used basic output stream and it works now! tnx Jon!